# Why android required to pass activity's instance in any widget's constructor

Tags: java, android

My background is Java, Swing, JavaFX that's why I'm confused in Android. Why each component(Button, ListView, EditText) or any other widget required to pass `activity's` instance.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);
Button btnTag = new Button(this); // why need to pass this/activity here?
layout.addView(row); // this is the layout in which we are placing button
                    // then why we need to pass activity's instance as parameter?
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually they don't need an `Activity` but a `Context` (`Activity` is a class derived from it, so it is a good candidate to be passed to `View`s' constructors). `Context` in Android is something like a God object, through which you can access resources, application state, device's resources, etc.

All the classes you mentioned are *sons* of `View`, and its constructor requires a `Context` (then also the derived classes' constructors). The [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View(android.content.Context)) says, about this parameter: ***Context***: The Context the view is running in, through which it can access the current theme, resources, etc.

Comment: Any example please? what do you mean by access resources? how and when? and we pass activity's instance not context.  Context is parent of activity?

Comment: `Context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white, null);` just to access to the white color

Comment: I think there is nothing related to `widget`

Comment: Say you want to access to the user-defined primary color (a very important thing for a UI element):         `TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
        Context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, value, true);
        int primaryColor = value.data;`

How can a widget (Button, EditText, etc) access it without a reference to a context?

Comment: I don't know what is the code to access resources from `Button`

Comment: Look with your eyes how a `TextView`, just for example, uses its `mContext` reference: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView

Answer (score 0):

A Context provides access to information about the application state. It provides Activities, Fragments, and Services access to resource files, images, themes/styles, and external directory locations. It also enables access to Android's built-in services, such as those used for layout inflation, keyboard, and finding content providers.

In many cases when the "context is required", we simply need to pass in the instance of the current activity. In situations where we are inside objects created by the activity such as adapters or fragments, we need to pass in the activity instance into those objects. In situations where we are outside of an activity (in an application or service), we can use the "application" context instead.

for more info take a look at this [owesome tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-Context).

as for your question the Button and TextView and any other widget in android extend View and view needs the context to obtain some values from resources like the default theme. look at [View source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#4925) and search for mContext.